# how to get a list of all paths/files on a webpage using wget or curl in php?

Tags: php, curl, header, wget

I use `wget -p $url`  to get all the files on a webpage so that I can get a list. But for some URLs, it turns out that only the index.html can be fetched by wget. Is there a way to get a list of files on a specific URL by wget or cURL? Do I need to check the request headers and response headers?

Comment: You'll get better responses if you can make some examples. What do the links look like that wget doesn't follow?

Comment: @Pekka, eg: wget -p amazon.com   and I get only the index.html.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "files on a webpage"? `wget -p` loads all the prerequisites, ie. attached style sheets and the like. Is that what you want?

Comment: @Pekka, you may type some url on the page: tools.pingdom.com, and the list of files is what I want. Actually I get this kind of file list for some websites by using "wget -p", but for many other websites it only download the index.html. Do you have any suggestion how I can get this kind of list of files?

Answer (score 2):

Some servers do not let you browse directory listings, and if there's a default document in that directory, it takes over and you can't browse either.

You need to implement a spider that parses all the paths and files and links, and creates a directory structure of files that are declared and used in the HTML. **Then** you can download those files.

Comment: You may type some url on the page: http://tools.pingdom.com, and the list of files is what I want. Do you know how can I get this kind of list of all files?