# Why does wget only download the index.html for some websites?

Tags: wget

I'm trying to use wget command:

```
wget -p http://www.example.com
```

to fetch all the files on the main page. For some websites it works but in most of the cases, it only download the index.html. I've tried the wget -r command but it doesn't work. Any one knows how to fetch all the files on a page, or just give me a list of files and corresponding urls on the page?

Comment: How does this differ from your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123477/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-paths-files-on-a-webpage-using-wget-or-curl-in-php)? If it's the same problem, edit your old question to clarify it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get a list of all paths/files on a webpage using wget or curl in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123477/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-paths-files-on-a-webpage-using-wget-or-curl-in-php)

Answer (score 111):

Wget is also able to download an entire website. But because this can put a heavy load upon the server, wget will obey the robots.txt file.

```
wget -r -p http://www.example.com
```

The -p parameter tells wget to include all files, including images. This will mean that all of the HTML files will look how they should do.

So what if you don't want wget to obey by the robots.txt file? You can simply add -e robots=off to the command like this:

```
wget -r -p -e robots=off http://www.example.com
```

As many sites will not let you download the entire site, they will check your browsers identity. To get around this, use -U mozilla as I explained above.

```
wget -r -p -e robots=off -U mozilla http://www.example.com
```

A lot of the website owners will not like the fact that you are downloading their entire site. If the server sees that you are downloading a large amount of files, it may automatically add you to it's black list. The way around this is to wait a few seconds after every download. The way to do this using wget is by including --wait=X (where X is the amount of seconds.)

you can also use the parameter: --random-wait to let wget chose a random number of seconds to wait. To include this into the command:

```
wget --random-wait -r -p -e robots=off -U mozilla http://www.example.com
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried the 3 ways you mentioned on some common urls (amazon.com for example) but what I get was only the index.html. Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: same here. Only index.html

Comment: @JayH try to not use an address that will be redirected. I.E if you use ```http://amazon.com``` it will not work because you'll be redirected to www.amazon.com, but if you'll use ```http://www.amazon.com``` it will start to download all the site.
The ability to not to follow robots file is something not so "polite" so it will not work as good as you can imagine.

Comment: I hate how the most valued answer is at the bottom of the site

Comment: In addition to `--random-wait` also can be used parameter `-w X` where `X` is a time in seconds and it is used as a base value to calculate what the random wait times will be.

Answer (score 43):

Firstly, to clarify the question, the aim is to download `index.html` plus all the requisite parts of that page (images, etc). The `-p` option is equivalent to `--page-requisites`.

The reason the page requisites are not always downloaded is that they are often hosted on a different domain from the original page (a CDN, for example). By default, [wget refuses to visit other hosts](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Spanning-Hosts.html), so you need to **enable host spanning with the `--span-hosts` option**.

```
wget --page-requisites --span-hosts 'http://www.amazon.com/'
```

If you need to be able to load `index.html` and have all the page requisites load from the local version, you'll need to add the `--convert-links` option, so that URLs in `img` src attributes (for example) are rewritten to relative URLs pointing to the local versions.

Optionally, you might also want to save all the files under a single "host" directory by adding the `--no-host-directories` option, or save all the files in a single, flat directory by adding the `--no-directories` option.

Using `--no-directories` will result in lots of files being downloaded to the current directory, so you probably want to specify a folder name for the output files, using `--directory-prefix`.

```
wget --page-requisites --span-hosts --convert-links --no-directories --directory-prefix=output 'http://www.amazon.com/'
```

Comment: Thanks for the valuable answer. Can you please add some extra info to make it more general before I can award you the bounty. Like, for example, `http://indiabix.com/civil-engineering/questions-and-answers/` under this link , I want wget to visit each category/chapter and download all the images,from every page in  every sections (on left sidebar). Notice, by images,I mean all images including the images of Math formulae involved in the questions.
*Problem is that the download stops after downloading index.html. A working example for this case would be great !!!*

Comment: @InsaneCoder You might want to start a separate question for that and show what you've tried, as recursive fetching is a whole other set of problems, and (as I understand it) isn't what the original question was asking about.

Comment: @InsaneCoder Adding the `--mirror` option is the most straightforward, and might be enough for your needs.

Comment: Be careful to use `--span-hosts`, add `-D<domain-list>` to limit spanning to certain domains.

Comment: @EvanHu Adding a whitelist of domains wouldn't help here, as wget needs to be able to fetch the page requisites wherever they're hosted.

Comment: @AlfEaton thanks for your concern. Can you try `wget -rkEpHN  -e robots=off  -U mozilla   http://www.yinwang.org/` and `wget -rkEpHN -Dyinwang.org -e robots=off  -U mozilla   http://www.yinwang.org/` and check the results?

Comment: @EvanHu Those commands are using the `-r` (recursive) flag, so are not relevant to this question/answer.

Comment: `--span-hosts` along with `--domain=` saved me. I had a website with images on ststic subdomain, so wget couldn't retrive them

Answer (score 8):

The link you have provided is the homepage or /index.html, Therefore it's clear that you are getting only a index.html page. For an actual download, for example, for "test.zip" file, you need to add the exact file name at the end. For example use the following link to download test.zip file:

> wget -p domainname.com/test.zip

**Download a Full Website Using `wget --mirror`**

Following is the command line which you want to execute when you want to download a full website and made available for local viewing.

> wget --mirror -p --convert-links -P ./LOCAL-DIR 
>   http://www.example.com

- –mirror: turn on options suitable for mirroring.
- -p: download all files that are necessary to properly display a given HTML page.
- –convert-links: after the download, convert the links in document 
  for local viewing.
- -P ./LOCAL-DIR: save all the files and directories to the specified directory

**Download Only Certain File Types Using `wget -r -A`**

You can use this under following situations:

- Download all images from a website,
- Download all videos from a website,
- Download all PDF files from a website

> wget -r -A.pdf http://example.com/test.pdf

Comment: Thanks. The `--mirror` option was what finally made it work for me.

Answer (score 5):

Another problem might be that the site you're mirroring uses links without `www`. So if you specify

`wget -p -r http://www.example.com`

it won't download any linked (intern) pages because they are from a "different" domain. If this is the case then use

`wget -p -r http://example.com`

instead (without `www`).

Comment: Correct observation. This is the root cause for my problem.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem downloading files of CFSv2 model. I solved it using mixing of the above answers, but adding the parameter `--no-check-certificate`

`wget -nH --cut-dirs=2 -p -e robots=off --random-wait -c -r -l 1 -A "flxf*.grb2" -U Mozilla --no-check-certificate https://nomads.ncdc.noaa.gov/modeldata/cfsv2_forecast_6-hourly_9mon_flxf/2018/201801/20180101/2018010100/`

Here a brief explanation of every parameter used, for a further explanation go to the [GNU wget 1.2 Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html)

- `-nH` equivalent to `--no-host-directories`: Disable generation of host-prefixed directories. In this case, avoid the generation of the directory `./https://nomads.ncdc.noaa.gov/`
- `--cut-dirs=<number>`: Ignore  directory components. In this case, avoid the generation of the directories `./modeldata/cfsv2_forecast_6-hourly_9mon_flxf/`
- `-p` equivalent to `--page-requisites`: This option causes Wget to download all the files that are necessary to properly display a given HTML page. This includes such things as inlined images, sounds, and referenced stylesheets.
- `-e robots=off`: avoid download robots.txt file
- `-random-wait`: Causes the time between the request to vary between 0.5 and 1.5 * seconds, where  was specified using the `--wait` option.
- `-c` equivalent to `--continue`: continue getting a partially-downloaded file.
- `-r` equivalent to `--recursive`: Turn on recursive retrieving. The default maximum depth is 5
- `-l <depth>` equivalent to `--level <depth>`: Specify recursion maximum depth level
- `-A <acclist>` equivalent to `--accept <acclist>`: specify a comma-separated list of the name suffixes or patterns to accept.
- `-U <agent-string>` equivalent to `--user-agent=<agent-string>`: The HTTP protocol allows the clients to identify themselves using a User-Agent header field. This enables distinguishing the WWW software, usually for statistical purposes or for tracing of protocol violations. Wget normally identifies as ‘Wget/version’, the version being the current version number of Wget.
- `--no-check-certificate`: Don't check the server certificate against the available certificate authorities.

Comment: It was the -e robots=off that did it for me!

Answer (score 3):

I know that this thread is old, but try what is mentioned by Ritesh with:

> --no-cookies

It worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

If you look for `index.html` in [the **wget manual**](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#index-index_002ehtml-73) you can find an option `--default-page=name` which is `index.html` by default. You can change to `index.php` for example.

```
--default-page=index.php
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only get the `index.html` and that file looks like it only contains binary data (i.e. no readable text, only control characters), then the site is probably sending the data using `gzip` compression.

You can confirm this by running `cat index.html | gunzip` to see if it outputs readable HTML.

If this is the case, then `wget`'s recursive feature (`-r`) won't work. There is a [patch](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-wget/2014-12/msg00087.html) for `wget` to work with gzip compressed data, but it doesn't seem to be in the standard release yet.