# How can I get wget to download all the pdf files from this website?

Tags: html, pdf, wget

The website is: https://dgriffinchess.wordpress.com/

I already downloaded the entire website, but I'd also like to have the pdf files, and yes, I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8756067/7207820), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11124664/7207820) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/331752/197020) answer, and unless wget saves the pdf files other than the main site folder(the one at the Home directory), I don't see them downloading at all..(I don't wait until the command finishes, I just wait for a few minutes and see that no pdf file has been downloaded yet, and considering that there is one almost on every webpage, I conclude that the pdf's aren't getting downloaded) 
I don't really care if I have to re-download the entire website again, it's not that big to begin with, what matters most to me are the .pdf files, which doesn't seem to download in any way..

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The PDF files are stored on another domain, `dgriffinchess.files.wordpress.com`.

To completely download this website along with the PDF files, you need to authorize the domain name where the PDF files are stored using `--span-hosts` and `--domains=domain_a,domain_b`:

```
wget --recursive --page-requisites --convert-links --span-hosts --domains=dgriffinchess.wordpress.com,dgriffinchess.files.wordpress.com https://dgriffinchess.wordpress.com/
```